# Attribute error when handling missing categorical data

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, nan, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to fill NaN categorical values using `CategoricalImputer` from `sklearn_pandas`.

```
from sklearn_pandas import CategoricalImputer
imputer = CategoricalImputer()

nan_columns = train_df.loc[:, train_df.isnull().any()]

for column in nan_columns:
  imputer.fit_transform(column)
```

But `imputer.fit_transform(column)` gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

I'm doing this following the documentation. Where am I going wrong?

**Edit**:

I added this cell:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

nan_columns = train_df.loc[:, train_df.isnull().any()]
imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")

imputer.fit_transform(train_df)
msno.bar(train_df.sample(1000), labels=True, fontsize=8)
```

However, it didn't work. This is the bar graph showing that there are still missing values in the columns:

[image]

Comment: According to the [README](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/sklearn-pandas#200-2020-08-01) `CategoricalImputer` has been removed since version 2.0.0 because you can instead use `SimpleImputer` from scikit-learn.

Comment: @AaronKeesing How do you use SimpleImputer for categorical values? The docs only show numerical values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SimpleImputer` from scikit-learn with categorical values by using `strategy="most_frequent".

```py
imp = SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": ["a", "a", np.nan],
                   "y": ["c", np.nan, "c"],
                   "z": ["a", np.nan, np.nan]})
print(df)
df[:] = imp.fit_transform(df)
print(df)
```

yields

```
     x    y    z
0    a    c    a
1    a  NaN  NaN
2  NaN    c  NaN

   x  y  z
0  a  c  a
1  a  c  a
2  a  c  a
```

If you only want to use it on string or categorical columns:

```py
for col, tp in df.dtypes.items():
    if tp == object or tp.name == "category":
        df[col] = imp.fit_transform(df[[col]])
```

Comment: It didn't work. The code did not inflate the NaN values. Check the edits.

Comment: You're not actually assigning back to `train_df` though. `fit_transform()` returns a copy.

Comment: How can I plot the returned copy?

Comment: It returns an array, so you'll need to create a new dataframe from that. Then you can plot as usual. Or you can copy your original dataframe, then to something like `df_copy[:] = imp.fit_transform(df_copy)`.

Comment: Yea but the imputer's returns are assigned to only those specific columns `train_df[col] = imputer.fit_transform(train_df[[col]])`

Comment: Why is that a problem?